# React, webpack and creating a bundle using a per build json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We would like to create bundle.js from React and webpack, where a per build configuration is included and made available to the React code, but we are not sure how to go about doing this.

The idea would be to be to do something like:

```
npm run build -- config="config123.json"
```

And then have the generated bundle.js include that configuration, such that it could be used by the root container. Something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import RootContainer from './containers/main-container';

ReactDOM.render(
    <RootContainer config={configPassedByBuildProcess}/>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Is this possible and if so, how should we approach this?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe that you can pass a file on build, from what I know the only thing that you can pass is a string like an ENV variable. You could import the config123.json file like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import RootContainer from './containers/main-container';
import config from '/path/to/config123.json'
ReactDOM.render(
    <RootContainer config={config}/>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

You may need a JSON loader for importing JSON files

Comment: Does this answer the question? Or are you asking him a question? If so, questions and comments for the poster belong in the comments section under the question and not here. Then this should be deleted please.

Comment: it tells me that I must have 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: That gives you no permission to make comments in the answer section. Please delete this.

Comment: Just trying to help. I'll change my comment into an answer

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of experimenting, the solution I have found is to use Webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), since this provides a way of doing string substitution during webpack's build phase.

In my React code I defined:

```
// Will be substituted by webpack's DefinePlugin. Not an error.
const bundleConfig = BUNDLE_CONFIG;
```

and then in my `webpack.config.js` I first load my config (hard coded for now):

```
// The path can be pulled in via 'process.args' and parsed as appropriate
const bundleConfig = fs.readFileSync('bundle-config/default-config.json', 'UTF-8');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'BUNDLE_CONFIG': bundleConfig
    })
  ]
}
```

Note that if for some reason we want to build with a missing or undefined bundleConfig, then the right substitution would likely be the string (not the keyword) `'undefined'` , to keep the code valid, such that:

```
const bundleConfig = 'undefined';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'BUNDLE_CONFIG': bundleConfig
    })
  ]
}
```

Just one extra thing was the configuration of the package.json (scripts section only):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "run() { NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p $1; }; run",
    }
}
```

This allow passing in the path to the `webpack.conf.js` script, when we call:

```
 npm run build /path/to/config.json
```